# How to delete the element from document in Mongodb?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, pull

I have this collection in MongoDB and I want to delete "Bangalore" as shown below.

```
{
    "_id": "1",
    "UserName": "Mike",
    "UserDetails": [{
        "UserCountryName": "India",
        "UserLocation": [
            "Bangalore",
            "Chennai",
            "Delhi",
            "Mumbai"
        ]
    }]
}
```

I tried the below query but it didn't work.
The whole UserDetails array is getting deleted.
I want only "Banglore" to be deleted.
Please help.

```
db.user.update( 
  { }, 
  { $pull: { "UserDetails": {"UserLocation":"Bangalore"} } } 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct option:

```
 db.user.update({},
{
 $pull: {
 "UserDetails.$[].UserLocation": "Bangalore"
 }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

Explained:
This is removing the value from all  UserDetails.$[].UserLocation array elements in all documents in the user collection.

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vhQocKN09Mf)

[playground(in option when more then one values need to be removed)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1iyMbBtQtY9)

Comment: Thank you R2D2 ..
I have one more similar scenario where my collection is as below
[
  {
    "network_type": "ex",
    "rack": [
      {
        "xxxx": {
          "asn": 111111,
          "nodes": {
            "business": [
              "sk550abcc1eb01.abc.com",
              "sk550abcc1eb10.abc.com",
              "sk550abcc1eb19.abc.com",
              "sk550abcc1eb28.abc.com"
            ]
          },
          "region": "ex-01",
          "zone": "01a"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]

I need to delete "sk550abcc1eb01.abc.com" , but the below query doesnt work.

Comment: db.collection.update({},
{
  $pull: {
    "rack": {
      "xxxx.nodes.$[].business": {
        $in: [
          "sk550abcc1eb01.abc.com"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
Please help

Comment: check here , is more or less the same:  https://mongoplayground.net/p/S0zbvBNcyMr